# How to customize dropdown scrollbar in PrimeNG

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

I am new to Angular, and am trying to customize the scrollbar on a PrimeNG dropdown, without success.  Does anyone know how to do this?

HTML:

```
<p-autoComplete placeholder="- Select -" (onSelect)="onSelect(dh.head,i)" (onClear)="clearData($event,dh.head, i)" (onDropdownClick)="handleDropdown(event)" field="name" [suggestions]="filteredData" [(ngModel)]="dh.head" (completeMethod)="search($event,i)" [dropdown]="true">
            <ng-template let-colval pTemplate="item">
              <div innerHTML="{{colval.name | highlight:dh.head}}"></div>
            </ng-template>
          </p-autoComplete>
```

CSS for dropdown panel containing scrollbar:

```
.ui-autocomplete .ui-autocomplete-panel {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 290% !important;
}
```

I have tried adding the following CSS to the component:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
  border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
```

But it has no effect on the dropdown scrollbar.  Any ideas?  Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Where you place your CSS has an impact on when your CSS gets loaded.  From my experience, you need to load style-changing CSS for PrimeNG components before PrimeNG loads.  Otherwise, the Angular component namespacing takes over and you can't change the styles from outside of the component.

Comment: That was it!  When I loaded the webkit stuff in my globalstyles.css it changed the dropdown scrollbar.  Thank you!  If you post this as an answer I will check it off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to load the CSS styles for the PrimeNG Components you want to modify before PrimeNG is loaded.

This occurs because once PrimeNG has loaded, the styles are encapsulated inside the Angular component namespaces.

Comment: You got it! Good luck!

Comment: In my case, I put css code in to `src/style.css` is work